# "for" versus "of", meaning "concerning someone or something"

Tags: prepositions

Consider:

> Netting is a clause in virtuall all agreements **for** derivatives that will be cleared bilaterally.
>
> Basel III: A Global Regulatory Framework **for** More  Resilient  Banks  and  Banking  Systems.
>
> The average gross income over the last three years **for** each business line.
>
> The New Challenge **for** Financial Markets. The regulatory capital requirements **for** credit risk. Monte Carlo simulation **for** loans in the portfolio over a one-year period. The balance sheet **for** the oil company. The world record **for** the 100 meters.
>
> The result **of** the debate. A national shortage **of** teachers. The present value **of** future credit losses. Historical data on the credit spread changes **of** companies. Examples **of** scenarios of this type.

I think these "for" here fits the 3rd definition (concerning someone or something) in OALD, so does "of" (relating to). Some of these examples may be idiomatic, while others may be not.

But I wonder if "for" and "of" can be used interchangeably in some of these examples. Plz help to clarify.

Note: For this question I asked, "for + noun" examples are selected deliberately to qualify the noun for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You're making me work!  :)  You could indeed use "of" in some of these examples.  Some of them, we simply don't, some of them have a slightly different meaning, and some of them you could use either.  Some of them I'm not quite sure of, because I don't have specialized knowledge of financial terms.

The first one probably could substitute "involving" for "for".  The second one means that the framework is intended to cause more resilient banks.  If you used "of" the banks themselves would be the framework.  The third one could use of, but we generally say for in this case.  The same for all of the sentences in your fourth paragraph, except the last one; we would never say "the world record of the 100 meters."

"The result for the debate" would be less often seen than "of" as you have it here, but it might be used.  "A national shortage for teachers" would mean that there was something unspecified that teachers had a shortage of, for example "A national shortage of pencils for teachers".  Future credit losses possess a present value, therefore "of" is correct here.  The same for companies' credit spread changes.  If you used "for" here, you would be saying that credit spread changes didn't belong to companies, but existed independently on behalf of companies in some way.  Scenarios possess examples, so of is correct here.

The use of prepositions in any language is often arbitrary, and when they are they have to be learned by rote.

[Edit] I'll address your last question here.  This isn't perfect, but it might help to some degree.  "A for B" has a general meaning of A being in the service, under the control, or a part of B in some way.  "A to B" has a general meaning of connecting A and B, with A the agent of connection (a "vector" exists from A to B, if you will).  "A of B" means that B owns A in some manner.  As you can see, these explanations overlap to some extent, which is why some expressions are idiomatic and have to be learned, and some expressions can substitute for, of, and/or to.

"Severity for external fraud" should be "severity of external fraud".  The fraud "owns" the severity, and the severity isn't in the service or under the control of the fraud.  "A key ingredient for the success" could be right, and you could also use "of".  "An important decision for operational risk managers" seems best to me, since the decision is under the control of the managers.

[Here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/for%5b1%5d) is a list of ways in which for is used which may also help.

Comment: Actually I worked out a similar idea. Present value is inherent part of Future credit loss. The average gross income, I think, is also directly related to business lines, why is "for" used?

Comment: Please give an example sentence with the "for" in it.

Comment: The third one in my question!

Comment: Severity for external fraud, a key ingredient for the success, an important decision for operational risk managers. I can list more if you wish. @BobRodes

Comment: Acually it is "severity for external fraud" that my textbook on risk management writes. The author is John Hull. The book is Financial Institutions and Risk Management. @BobRodes

Comment: There are some contexts that I can think of that will use for, but not many. They would be situations in which the doesn't "own" the severity.  Can you provide more of the context?

Comment: Here we go, I found it.  "Suppose further that external data indicates that, for external fraud in corporate finance, the mean severity is twice that for internal fraud in corporate finance and the standard deviation of the severity is 1.5 times as great. In the absence of a better alternative, the bank might assume that its own severity for external fraud in corporate finance has a mean of 2 × 50,000 = $100,000 and a standard deviation of severity equal to 1.5 × 30,000 = $45,000. "

Comment: In this case you are talking about the mean value of severity in the case of external fraud, as compared to the severity level in the case of internal fraud.  So in this case, the fraud doesn't "own" the severity, it is a statistic in its own right.  This is atypical.  For example, "I'd like to compare the severity of external fraud to that of internal fraud" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> But I wonder if "for" and "of" can be used interchangeably in some of these examples. Plz help to clarify.

Sometimes. Not always.

Consider the sentence:

> What can I do *for* you?

*Of* won't fit in there (you = noun/subject).

> What can I do *of* you?

Consider:

> The life of the party.

*For* won't fit in there (party = noun/subject).

> The life for the party.

---

The easiest way to use *of* and *for* is to think of *of* as a *possessive preposition* (don't know if that's an actual thing).

> The temple *of* Isis. (Isis' temple)
>
> The waters of the River Nile. (The River Nile's waters)
>
> The cathedral of St. Paul. (St. Paul's cathedral)

And *for* is usually used when you want to add something to something else.

> The temple *for* Isis. (Temple was built for the goddess Isis)
>
> The waters for the River Nile. (The waters are to be given/put into the River Nile (perhaps a bottle of water from the Amazon to be added?))
>
> The cathedral for St. Paul. (Cathedral dedicated to St. Paul)

Therefore, you can construct sentences like this:

> The results **of** the debate showed a national shortage **of** teachers due to the present value **of** future credit losses. This can been seen given the historical data on the credit spread changes **for** companies, examples **of** these types **of** scenarios **for** this issue...

---

Another way is if you want to emphasize something on the *left*, use *of*. And on the *right*, use *for*.

> The temple *of* Isis.

Focus is on temple.

> I got this *for* you.

Focus is on you.